# diff binary files of different sizes?

Tags: diff, binary

Is there a neat way to see the difference between two binary files? They are mostly the same, but some bytes are changed, and one of the files has sequences inserted in some places.

Diffing the output of `xxd` would work if bytes were only changed, and not inserted.

Comment: i would graphically diff the hexdumps of both binaries with `vimdiff`

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux

Answer (score 8):

There are a few binary editors that can show differences between files, but the ones I've tried (`dhex` and `vbindiff`) don't seem to be able to detect and show insertions or deletions.

There are a number of binary diff utilities like `rdiff`, `xdelta` or `bsdiff` that compute the difference between two files. But the purpose is to generate `patch` files to be later applied to an original. You can't read those *patch files* to *see* what the differences are.

Something you can do, to visually see the difference, is to hexdump the files with one byte per line and `diff` the results. The line numbers will tell you the offset in the file (though beware it starts at 1, not 0):

```
diff -u <(od -w1 -vAn -tx1 file1) <(od -w1 -vAn -tx1 file2)
```

(assuming your `od` supports the non-standard `-w` option).

Answer (score 1):

try using [dhex](http://www.dettus.net/dhex/) or  [jojodiff](http://jojodiff.sourceforge.net/) .
You can also use `bsdiff`.

Comment: bsdiff looks like xdelta, wonder wich generates the smaller binary patch tho..